# Xcode insists that there is an "invalid character in bundle identifier" that does not appear to exist

Tags: xcode, bundle-identifier

I'm working on my first app to get a feel for how adding google ads works (it's just a basic front facing flashlight app) and when i create a bundle ID, I get this error: [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBozq.png)

My bundle ID is "com.dadams.Front-facing-LCD-Flashlight", and i do not believe it contains any characters that would not be allowed.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Please post error messages as text if possible.

Comment: Oh sorry, all the error message says is "invalid character ' " and does not seem to finish it, also my current bundle ID is "com.dadams.FrontFacingLCDFlashlight". Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think Xcode is adding dashes where invalid characters are appearing. Spaces are not allowed in a bundle identifier, so Xcode is adding the dashes where the spaces are. Try getting rid of them and cleaning the project.

Answer (score 0):

Your bundle Identifier is com.dadam.Front-facing LCD Flashlight according to the image you posted. Try your bundel Identifier without the "-". You are only allowed to use alpha numeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

Bundle identifiers must be UTI compliant.

From the documentation:

> **The UTI Character Set**
>
> A uniform type identifier is a Unicode string
> that usually contains characters in the ASCII character set. However,
> only a subset of the ASCII characters are permitted. You may use the
> Roman alphabet in upper and lower case (**A–Z, a–z**), the **digits 0
> through 9**, the **dot (“.”**), and the **hyphen (“-”**). This restriction is
> based on DNS name restrictions, set forth in RFC 1035.

Comment: My bundle identifier follows all of these guidelines, though. There is nothing inside it that would go against it being UTI compliant. What I think Xcode thinks is that there is a bunch of blank space after my bundle ID inside info.plist, but i checked and there is not any.